# Using the Windows Driver Kit (wdm.h specifically) functions in a Windows Desktop Application and/or Console Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, driver, wdk, kmdf

I have a necessity to use the `ZwSetValueKey()` function declared in the `Wdm.h` header file available as a part of the Windows Driver Kit (WDK) to access the registry keys created by a kernel mode driver but Visual Studio does not allow the use of the WDK headers as it fails to detect the required header file when included (by referring to the error message stating that `Wdm.h` cannot be opened).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `wdm.h` header file containing the `ZwXXXX` functions are unsuited for use in applications that do not run in the kernel mode (as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/drivers/ff567122(v=vs.85))). The equivalent `NtXXXX` functions in `winternl.h` and `Ntdll.dll`, on the other hand, are accessible for use as a part of the Windows Native System Services routine by applications running in the user mode.

In the context of the function enlisted in the question, the function `NtSetValueKey()` can be used in its substitute (as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwsetvaluekey#remarks)).